# Django-PayPal and new PayPal security rules

Tags: django, ssl, django-paypal

I'm integrating my Django site with PayPal payments pro. I'm following the [Django-PayPal](https://django-paypal.readthedocs.org/en/stable/pro/index.html) guide, and all runs perfectly... But, when I post the payment.html, I get the following message:

```
"[SSL: SSLV3_ALERT_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE] sslv3 alert handshake failure (_ssl.c:590)"
```

There are some security updates on PayPal API:

- PayPal is upgrading SSL certificates on all Live and Sandbox endpoints from SHA-1 to the stronger and more robust SHA-256 algorithm.
- Discontinue use of the VeriSign G2 Root Certificate.

I think that this is the cause of my bug... I'm working on my localhost. How can I fix my Django-PayPal integration for new standards?... Thank you.

Comment: What is your OpenSSL version? Paypal has started disabling TLS versions 1.0 and 1.1, and TLS 1.2 is only supported with OpenSSL 1.0.1c+.

Comment: Hi @MattO, I was working with "OpenSSL 0.9.8zg 14 July 2015". I updated the openSSL version and now the "openssl version" command shows "OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016", but is not running yet. The post shows the same bug.

Comment: Fixed runing export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:~/bin:$PATH" before force link, and running pip install pyopenssl ndg-httpsclient pyasn1 on my virtualenv.